# CSS not applied in bootstrap modal on my Rails app

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, bootstrap-modal

Following is my bootstrap setup:

Rails ver: 4.1.1

Gemfile:

```
  gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.2.0'
  gem 'bootstrap3-datetimepicker-rails', '~> 3.0.2'
  gem 'bootstrap-validator-rails'
```

Application.css.scss (first 3 imports, no require directives)

```
   @import "bootstrap-sprockets";
   @import "bootstrap";
   @import "bootstrap-datetimepicker";
```

Application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery.flexslider
//= require jquery.turbolinks
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery-ui/autocomplete
//= require ./plugins/bootstrap-select.js
//= require ./plugins/jquery.form.js
//= require bootstrap-datetimepicker
//= require bootstrapValidator.min
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require_tree .
```

Modal HTML:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">x</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
      <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel"> Title </h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
       <%= render partial: 'modal_body' %>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">      
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Mark</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

I am able to render the modal but the modal takes up the entire width of the window.
[image]

Comment: post your modal html code as well

Comment: @RameshKumarThiyagarajan updated.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `Application.css.scss`,

rename you file to `Application.scss`.

`mv Application.css.scss Application.scss`